# SSRS shows wrong form

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am learning SSRS from a book. The book tells me to modify a simple existing report as follows -

1. Create a new Form (windows forms) and use the RDLC file of the original report.
2. Use the report wizard to select data source and eventually create your report.

When I try to run the modified report, visual studio shows me the old one instead. How do I fix this ?

**old report -**

[image]

**The modified report -**

[image]

**When I rebuild the solution and debug it and try to run modified report, it shows 
me the old report instead.**

[image]

**EDITS -**

My project structure -

[image]

Comment: correct me if I am wrong this is not ssrs 2008 its 2005?

Comment: @M.Ali - it is ssrs 2008 for sure. I am using bids/vs 08 and sql server 2008 and book for 08.

Comment: hit the little refresh button on the report preview, that shows up in 2012 as well, that usually fixes it.

Comment: @DanielE. - I clicked on the refresh button shown in the third image. It does not help.

Comment: if you are debugging is it starting the "Starting report" which would still be report 1?  Can you deploy the report and see if it actually uses the updated report?  I have not used SSRS 2008 extensively, this is just a guess.

Comment: PS - I also chose the correct report for modified report from the "ReportViewer Tasks" menu. I can't take its screen, so I'll show what it looks like - http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC131499.gif

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see the edited question which has the project structure. I tried a workaround that works -

This happens because of `start item` setting in visual studio. To change this -

```
solution explorer > right click your vb (winforms) project > properties 
> application side-tab > Startup form: Form2 (ie the form that points to 
modified report)
```

Rebuild the project and you will get the modified form/report instead of the original one. 
The problem with this approach is that you will have to change this all the time when you add a new form or report to your project.

Can someone help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Please use this settings where you are setting for the reportserver.                      protected string reportServer
{
    get
    {
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportServer"] + “{0}&rs:Parameters=false&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true“;
    }
}

Comment: @PrashantKumar - What is this - ` where you are setting for the reportserver` ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem and was able to resolve it by removing the cache data for the reports.

Comment: Thanks. But that did not help me. I copied the argument `/C DEL /S /Q "$(SolutionDir)\*.rdl.data"` as is. Do I have to replace `SolutionDir` with any folder location ?

Comment: You can also delete the cache through the GUI if you download [BIDS Helper](https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Delete%20Dataset%20Cache%20Files&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: you don't need to change anything

Comment: @PrashantKumar - please see my answer. can you help me to fix the issue that I mentioned at the end ? thanks.