# Clear SSRS cache with SQL code

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

To solve this problem - [SSRS shows wrong form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888731/ssrs-shows-wrong-form)
I tried to clear the SSRS cache. One post suggested that I use SQL to do so - 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/58caa380-ece8-4507-9ff3-684c93685e72/how-to-clear-a-report-cache-in-ssrs-2008?forum=sqlreportingservices

The code -

```
Use ReportServer
EXEC FlushReportFromCache @Path
EXEC CleanExpiredCache
```

@Path you need to give path for report for which you need to clear cache.

Which path do I enter here ? I entered the folder which contains all my rdlc files and the sql gave me 0 rows returned. I am doing simple beginner exercises on a local system.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Path to your report that you want to clear from your cache. you can get this by querying the `dbo.Catalog` table in your ReportServer database something as follows:

```
USE ReportServer;
GO

SELECT  Name     --<-- Report Name
      ,[Path]    --<-- Report Path
FROM [dbo].[Catalog] 

GO
```

Comment: Thanks. I queried this and got only one row with blank characters.

Comment: M.Ali - How is your experience with SSRS ? It seems quite inconvenient to use. I am only doing a simple beginner exercise and cannot make it work.

Comment: The data should be there if you have created some reports and deployed. Experience with SSRS is great, it is a wonderful reporting tool, got many cool features but it has its moments when things just doesnt make any sense :). There are quite a few active bugs and some very simple functionality missing from it but hopefully things will get better with time. I havent worked with SSRS 2012 yet but I have heard that MS has tried to add some pretty cool features in it.